# What is the Meaning of Opportunities in Opportunities and Solutions Phase of ADM in TOGAF

Tags: togaf, enterprise-architecture

I have just started to explore TOGAF, as I am planning to get certified in it.

As I am going through the ADM phases, I understand that phase E (Opportunities and Solutions) is meant to be used in planning at initial level and idientify the delvery vehicles for the solutions for architectures defined in previous phases.

However was just wondering how does it justify its name i.e.Opportunities and Solutions?
What opportunities are we addressing over here, when we say so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phases B through D involve defining the baseline and target architectures for each of the architecture domains, and identifying the gaps between the baseline and the target.

At the end of Phase D, you should have four sets of architecture definitions and four sets of gap analysis on each.

Phase E involves consolidating those identified gaps into work packages. Those collectively are the opportunities. The gaps between the baseline (current) architecture and the target (future) architecture are the opportunities. Then you take those requirements and put them into the roadmap and draft implementation plan, and that's the solution element.

Hope it helps.

Comment: By the way Friends .. Just wanted to put across the great news .. I am a TOGAF CERTIFIED EA now :) :) :) .. And just wanted to thank all the people from across the streams who've supported me through my journey :)

Comment: Congrats valencoin! Great to hear. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the Architecture Development Method (ADM) in TOGAF, the Opportunities and Solutions phase is the third phase, which follows the Preliminary and Architecture Vision phases.

The Opportunities and Solutions phase focuses on identifying and assessing opportunities for change and improvement in the organization, and developing potential solutions that address these opportunities. The term "opportunities" in this phase refers to any potential business requirements, problems, or challenges that could be addressed through changes to the enterprise architecture.

Opportunities may arise from various sources, including changes in business strategy, new technologies, or changes in market conditions. The purpose of this phase is to identify these opportunities, assess their impact on the enterprise, and develop potential solutions that can be evaluated and prioritized based on their feasibility, business value, and alignment with the organization's goals and objectives.

The Solutions in this phase refer to the potential approaches, architectures, and designs that can be used to address the identified opportunities. These solutions will be further refined and developed in subsequent phases of the ADM, such as the Architecture Definition and Implementation phases, to create a detailed architecture that can be implemented to achieve the desired business outcomes.